# Finding text of legislation in India

Tags: india, family-law, legal-research, reference-request

Where can I find the text of the The Protection of Women from Domestic Violence Act, 2005?

Comment: The close flags claim the question is "too broad" which makes no sense as it is very specific, albeit, originally a bit inaptly phrased.

Answer (score 1):

The link to a pdf in the original answer is now broken, so here is the online version from India Code of the [The Protection of Women from Domestic Violence Act, 2005](https://www.indiacode.nic.in/handle/123456789/2021?view_type=search&sam_handle=123456789/1362).

And, as a backup, here's [The Protection of Women from Domestic Violence Act, 2005](https://indiankanoon.org/doc/542601/) from the Indian Kanoon.

Answer (score -1):

A pdf can be found here, it's a scan of the act but should suffice:

http://www.jklaw.nic.in/The_Jammu_and_Kashmir_Protection_of_Women_from_Domestic_Violence_Act,2010.pdf

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11574)

Comment: @PatW. Honestly, in this case, the link is the only essential part of the answer to a very reasonable question. I don't see why either this question or the answer would be down voted. Somebody had a legitimate question and somebody else answered it. That is what we do. Not every question calls for analysis in the body text.

Comment: @ohwilleke While I didn't downvote the question, it's probably fair to disagree about this.  My take would be that there's a Q&A aspect to Law.SE, which both this question and the answer satisfy, but that there's also a content-development-for-posterity aspect.  It's less justifiable on the latter grounds, and that's probably why the algorithm prompts us to take a look at these.